# How to Pass Array From Ajax Request To Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

By using Stringify, I can retrieve the data but I do not know how to pass it to javascript variable. It passes **[{"0":"1","ItemNumberFK":"1"},{"0":"2","ItemNumberFK":"2"},{"0":"3","ItemNumberFK":"3"}]** I dont know but I want to fetch the numbers **1,2,3** only how can i do that

JQUERY:

```
         $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#OrderPackageNumber").change(function(event){
        // You just get the value of selected input
        // You don't need to find anything because you've already selected it
        var selectedd = $(this).val();
        alert(selectedd);
        //id_numbers = new Array();

        var displayString = new Array();
         $.ajax({ 
               url:'getitemsofpackage.php',
               dataType:'json',
               type:'post',
               data:{ namee: selectedd },
               success:  function(data) {
                    console.log(data);

                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));



                },error: function(stats, exception){

              var msg = '';
                if (stats.status === 0) {
                    msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                } else if (stats.status == 404) {
                    msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                } else if (stats.status == 500) {
                    msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    msg = 'Time out error.';
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                } else {
                    msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + stats.responseText;
                }
                alert(msg);
               // return false;
            }


        });

    });
});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT ItemNumberFK FROM tblpackageitem WHERE PackageNumberFK = '".$namee."'     ;");


         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                //echo '<option value ="' . $row['PackageNumber'] . '" '. $selected .'>' . $row[1] . '</option>';
                //echo '<input type="checkbox" value= "' . $row['ItemNumber'] . '"   >' . $row['ItemName'];                 
                //echo $row['ItemPrice'];
                //echo "<br>";
             $arrayOfItems[] = $row;
                // $strTry = $row;
        }


// play with return result array 
//while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){   
    //$selectBoxOption1 .="<option value = '".$row['bike_type']."'>".$row['bike_type']."</option>"; 
//}
// return options


echo json_encode($arrayOfItems);
```

Comment: have you tried `JSON.parse` or just selecting it outright? `data[0][0]` etc.

Comment: parse data in json `JSON.parse(data:{ namee: selectedd }),`

Comment: numbers will be pushed to displayString variable: `JSON.parse(data).forEach(obj => displayString.push(obj.ItemNumberFK))`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code can help , the first **for** will get the rows , the second **for** will get what you want , in this case you will log all the values in the row.

```
for(var key in data){
    var row= data[key];
    for(var sub_key in row){
        console.log(val[sub_key]);
    }
}
```